# Data warehouse - OLTP

Tags: data-warehouse, olap, oltp

I'm doing this paper work for university about DataWarehouse, more specifically about OLTP. I couldn't find much information on the web. I find general and superficial summaries, but nothing that coould give me the possibility to do a more detailed work.

I would really apreciate any help about finding that kind of information, which im a bit lost right now.

So, is there any pdf ou e-book or something which i can use to base my work?

Thanks in advanced,
John

PS. about OLTP, datawarehouse i can find enought information

Comment: no. oltp - online transaction processing

Comment: It is usually data warehouse vs. OLTP. You either optimize your database schema for fast transaction processing (OLTP) or for fast reporting and analytics (data warehouse, OLAP).

Comment: John is correct. OLTP is not a part of warehousing. It is a *source* for warehouses, but not a component. I'd double check what your paper is asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats true, there isn't so much papers about. Books are the best source for this topic.
I don't have so much information, but some links may help. Tell me if this is what you are looking for.
What kind of transaction are you interesting: cards, stock market?

Algorithms: [Message passing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing), [subscribe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish/subscribe), [AMQP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol).
Enterprise standards: [PCI](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/index.php)
Protocols: [ISO 8583](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8583), [FIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIX_protocol)
A famous OLTP product: [FIS](http://www.fisglobal.com/products-card-creditcard)
Books: [a](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558601902), [b](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558606238), [1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0982611609), [2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9814302074)